# How to engage a module in Axis1?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis

In Axis2 I know it is possible to engage a module as below:

```
stub._getServiceClient().engageModule("myloggingmod");
```

How can this be done in Axis1?

Answer (score 1):

Modules have been introduced in Axis2, [**Axis1 does not have modules**](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/migration.html#custom_deployment).

Axis1 works with handlers, so at best, you could try to achieve what you are trying to do by configuring some handler. If I'm not mistaken you can even add one programmatically by getting hold of the handler chain:

```
stub._getService().getHandlerRegistry().getHandlerChain(portName);
```